# List all files from a URL android

Tags: android, file, url

I need to get the name of all files inside a folder given by a url. Suppose the webserver has a directory www.example.com/images/ and the folder contains files 1.png, 2.png and 3.png. I need to get the names of these image files using the url to the directory.

Comment: You need to develop a Web Service that explore the "images" dir and returns (by soap or RESTfull) the list of names. This WebService mus be invoked by your Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but the webserver might allow directory listing and then it produces a text or html page listing the files in that directory. You can then parse that response.

Test if the webserver allows directory listing by accessing the url in a browser: `www.example.com/images/` and see what response you get. Is it a file listing of some sort then you can parse that response.

Comment: thanks.. yea i do get a file listing when i access that url in a browser, but couldnt figure out a way to parse it..

Comment: Manually, indexOf, regexp etc